# Firebase database rules "hasChildren"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I was writing security rules in my database but I do not understand why the validation does not pass it ..
I just want people to be able to type in "Extra" if the key says "nombre".
In case it's not the key "nombre", don't let it.

[image]

the rules:

```
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
          ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).exists() === false || newData.hasChild('Extra')",
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['nombre'])",
             "Extra":{ 
             
               }
             }
           }
         }
```

**Is the writing rule wrong? Does someone explain to me why?**

**TEST1** wrong

[image]
[image]

**TEST2**

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're writing to location `/Users/$uid/Extra`, so the `nombre` property ends up in `/Users/$uid/Extra/nombre`. To test the rule, you'll want to write to `/Users/$uid`.

---

If instead  you want to allow the JSON like this:

```
Users: {
  myUserId: {
    Extra: {
      nombre: "MT Designer"
    }
  }
}
```

Then your rules currently don't work, because you're validating that `nombre` exissts under `myUserId`. It should be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).exists() === false || newData.hasChild('Extra')",
        "Extra":{ 
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['nombre'])",             
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Update: 2020-07-10**

From the new screenshots it seems that yyou haven't applied the change from above yet, so I'd first recommend doing that. But if you want to reject other child nodes in `Extra`, you can do that by changing the rules to:

```
"Extra":{ 
  "nombre": {
    ".validate": "data.isString()"
  },
  "$other": {
    ".validate": false
  },
}
```

So this validates that the name is a string, and rejects all other child nodes.

---

From comments, apparently this is what OP ended up with:

```
"Users": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).exists() === false || newData.hasChild('Extra')",
        "$othernode": {
            ".validate": false
        },
        "Extra": {
            "nombre": {
                ".validate": "newData.isString()"
            },
            "$other": {
                ".validate": false
            },
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Right ... I mean the validation is being applied to /Users /$uid ... I need it to only allow writing to /Users /$uid/ Extra .... something its wrong

Comment: Should I put the information that is in Users/$ uid in a node like "Information" and put specific rules on it? so that I can put other node "Extra" also specific rules?

Comment: Try with what you said "Extra":{ 
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['nombre'])",             
        } but it does not work ... in the image of TEST1 it is verified that it lets you write anything else ...

Comment: The simulator sometimes says one thing ... sometimes says another ... he is very crazy.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having a hard time parsing what the problem is. Can you: 1) change your console language to english (by adding `?hl-en` to its URL) and retake the screenshot, 2) show the entire playground in the screenshot, so that I can see the path and data you're writing there too? 3) then show one case that you want the rules to allow and one case that you want the rules to reject?

Comment: I want rules so that: in Users/$ uid they can write only once (when the account is generated) but in User/$ uid/Extra they can write whenever it is to modify the name only. As seen in the TEST1 image the validation lets me write anything in the Extra node and it shouldn't. There is a rule that is wrong. @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: In TEST2 the writing rule allows me to write any data even if the child('Extra') does not have.
There is something that is not working as it should.

Comment: Think I'm done ... I had to add what you told me in the node "Extra" .... but I also had to add another validation so that no more node can be added in Users / $uid. the rule stayed like this. it seems that the rule "newData.hasChild ('Extra')" doesn't do exactly that ... Can you modify your answer so i close the topic?

Comment: Good to hear you got it working. I added your rules to the answer. There's also an edit link for doing stuff like that btw.